# מוטות עץ שברת. כי באמרו ככה אשבור וכו׳ מעל צואר כל הגוים הרי הוא כאלו שבר כל המוטות: what's the translation to this metzudat dovid?

Tags: navi-prophets, jeremiah

This is from Yirmiyahu 28:13. מוטות עץ שברת. כי באמרו ככה אשבור וכו׳ מעל צואר כל הגוים הרי הוא כאלו שבר כל המוטות:
What's the translation to the above text? I'm having trouble translating it.

Answer (score 0):

Because by saying (after breaking the yoke that Yirmiuahu had on his neck): “so too shall I break [the yoke of Bavel] from upon the necks of all the nations!” - [by declaring that in G-d’s name, G-d considered that statement] as if he actually broke the yoke off all the nations!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be saying that because Chanayah the Prophet announced this prophesy about shattering the yoke of King Nebuchadnetzer *from off the neck of all the nations* within two years, which are compared to yokes of wood, *meaning lighter and softer burdens*, that it was as if he had decreed all yokes would be removed (which was not the true, intended message from G-d).

And Yirmiyahu the Prophet didn't contradict him, but said, it should only be so. But realize that many Prophets before him, including Yimiyahu himself, had received a very different message. But that if Chananyah's prophesy actually comes to pass, then everyone will know that he truly spoke in G-d's name.

Posuk 13 says that Yirmiyahu was told by G-d that by Chananyah's action, attempting to soften G-d's message, not only would the situation not improve, but that it would become worse through increased agitation. All the limitations that had been in place to limit agitation, would be removed.